# regular exp ends with exacr patterns

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression which matches words which start with BT followed by 5 digits, now I would like it to 
i)end with exactly G05 such that BT43424G05 will match. what should I modify the string patterns

```
^(?i)(BT)\d{5}

Match word : BT43424
```

Comment: Then add a 'G05' to the end of your regex ... ? You can have a play with your regex and what output you want [here](http://regexr.com?3038b).

Comment: can also test here http://www.pythonregex.com/ but seems like above mentioned is better regex test tool

Answer (score 1):

Try the below, you are allowed to include straight text in a regex if it has no regex-reserved meaning:

```
/^(?i)(BT)\d{5}G05$/
```